# How to add action to a JButton to execute another Java app.?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have java program with interface created using Java Swing. The interface contains a `JButton`. I want to add `Action` to that button so that it should execute another Java program which I specify.

How to do that?

Comment: do you have an initial piece of code

Comment: If you wish to run the new code in the same JRE as the one running the button, establish an `URLClassLoader` to the new Java app. then load and use the classes as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  yourButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          try {
              Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar A.jar");
          } catch (IOException ex) {

          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: See [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  **Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.**

Comment: Huh.. I voted down before I even saw `} catch (IOException ex) {

          }`  ..can I have another turn?  That should be `} catch (IOException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
          }`